# Finding general solution of differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How general solution of this form of differential equation can be found?
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {2y}{x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2y}{x} \hspace{10pt}\Leftrightarrow \hspace{10pt}\frac{dy}{2y}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
Now you just need to integrate.

Comment: @TPStar: It is a separable ODE.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I wrote...

Comment: okay that becomes
$$\frac {y^2}{4}dy = \log xdx$$ am i right?

Comment: No, That becomes $\frac12\ln y=\ln x+C$ and so $y=Cx^2$